# Setting window?.rootViewcontroller to UINavigationController with array of controllers

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, controllers

In AppDelegate, when I'm trying to do so -

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let controllerA = ControllerA()
let controllerB = ControllerB()

let nvc = UINavigationController()
nvc.viewControllers = [controllerA, controllerB]

window?.rootViewController = nvc
```

When I run the app, my second controller (ControllerB) has hidden navigationBar or is missing, I don't see navigationBar at all, but when I go back to controllerA , there is a navigationBar, why is it happens??

I need to have navigationBar on secondController...

[**RESOLVED**]

```
nvc.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: How do you display the second ViewController when being in the first one?

Comment: I set my rootViewcontroller to be a stack of ViewControllers

Comment: Yes, I can see it form the code snippet you provided, what I meant is how do navigate from the first one to the second? in order to display the second View controller you have to be -first- in the first View controller. Are you using a button or something? if you do, could you provide its code?

Comment: are you using `present()` for moving next viewController @blinkmeoff

Comment: You guys are kidding me? You are setting stack of view controllers, when you say nvc.viewControllers = [...] , and you are going automatically to the second one.  Anyhow, I resolved a problem, thanks.